# how do i (unit) test my handling of runtime exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

i have a small web application which does some simple data io via a gui front end.

so when the use hits 'save', the data is saved. On a runtime exception, i catch the exception, log it, and display a 'sorry etc.' label.

so as this code normally does not fail, and especially not when i want it to, there is no way for me to see if my 'sorry' label shows up and the 'succesfully saved' label is hidden.

Is there a nice solution for this?

the only way i could think of is to create a stub which throws an exception and via ioc load that stub when i want to check the 'fail' scenario's.
this creates some extra work, and does not help me when i first want to test the failure of step 1, and then the succes of step 1 and the failure of step 2.

I now do it manualy with inserting (and deleting) some throw exception commands, but that of course isn't very reliable.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint where the data is received by the server or the save commant fires? you can than invalidate the data in the debugger and see if the exception is thrown. But i would recommend to setup a unit test for this task to validate the correct functionality. But since i only work with Nunit i would wait if somebody shows up with a hint for VS internal testing.

Comment: this is one of the possibilities indeed. i also use the 'disconnect utp cable' technique once in a while

Comment: But for stable code you need to be independent from the UI. With a unit test you can just test by 1-click. Or insert a debug condition to the UI generating code. There you can set a invalidate flag to show the error content if you are just testing. But NUnit would be a good unit test environment.

Comment: i know. i do test the result code. problem is that it's not always easy to let the code fail (for example, no network connection available) and the second part is that i can't (easy) test if the user interface shows the right exception message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you should do is decouple the logic you are executing from the front end as much as possible.  Then you can write a test which checks that the logic is executed properly independently of the UI.

You could start by writing a class which takes an object representing the data to be saved and an interface representing the dependency which will do the saving (and perhaps a interface which represents the logging dependency).  Then you can write tests which pass a mock dependency which is configured to throw exceptions at the correct points, and invalid data which you can check the validation of.  You could also validate that the logging was performed as you expected. This class could return an object which represents the success or otherwise of the function and you could show the message or not based on that returned object.  If you are using MVC then you could validate theat the correct view is returned in the case of an error instead, but if not, then you are a bit stuck with the UI logic as far as testing goes and your only real option is to make the logic there as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to write a test which verifies that a specific error was thrown. Look at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.4 - the MSTest equivilant is ExpectedExceptionAttribute if that's your testing frameword  :o)

Answer (score 0):

Use RhinoMocks and code something like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {

        //Mocking is initialized
        MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();


        //Mock of interface is created
        ISomeClass someClass = mockRepository.Stub<ISomeClass>(); 


        //Setup that the method call results in an exception being thrown.
        someClass.Stub(x=> x.DoSomeThing()).Throw(new Exception());


        //Mock is "activated"
        mockRepository.ReplayAll();


        //Here the method is called and it does indeed throw an exception
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(someClass.DoSomeThing);

    }
```

Comment: its good to have an example, but it should be pointed out (just in case anyone who doesn't know any better thinks this is a good idea) that this code *is only testing rhino mocks* and not anything else.  really `someClass` should be injected into another instance of some other class and the test should verify that some expected behaviour in that class happened because of the thrown exception.

Comment: also, the newer AAA syntax is preferred over this older style.

Comment: @Sam: I agree that I should have written that I am only illustrating how the stub works. Regarding AAA syntax: Please enlighten me :o)